# Facebook Unity SDK Feed Dialog - iOS callbacks always "cancelled"

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Using the latest Facebook SDK for Unity, whenever I make a request using the FB.Feed API, and the user has the official Facebook App installed on iOS, the callback always returns "cancelled:true". If I however uninstall the official Facebook App from the iOS device, the callback returns the post ID as expected.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Adam

Comment: Have you got a solution?

Comment: Same is happening to me...

Comment: Long time and many patches later and still not resolved? Anyone managed to work out what the problem is?